# PHPUnit @covers impact on performance

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

I have a code base of 17.500 LOC (according to the coverage report) which will continue to grow. Unfortunately, running the tests and collecting the information for the code coverage with PHPUnit takes extremely long (30-45 minutes). Without code coverage/xdebug it's 2-3 minutes.

Since the code base also consists of a lot of in-house framework code which gets called quite often I was wondering if using the `@covers` annotation might have a positive impact on performance. Before implementing `@covers` annotation I would like to know if this annotation has an actual positive impact or not.

I would guess that on average every line gets covered 5 times which maybe causes a significant overhead that could be avoided (not to mention that a more strict coverage report is beneficial for me anyways). However, if `@covers` has no positive impact, implementing it is much lower on my priority list.

I do know that there are other alternatives to speed up the code coverage. E.g.

- Xdebug bootstrap script
- phpdbg
- Run separate coverage reports for application code and framework code

Comment: You do not want to use Xdebug for code coverage. PCOV is much, much faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no (positive) performance impact of using `@covers` annotations. All data will be collected and then it will be filtered, for instance based on these annotations.